# MSI GE70 laptop: bios fields change independent of user (i.e. user input)

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

My MSI GE70-2OE has experienced 3 curious incidents of bios changes in certain option fields, namely at least 2 fields where the user's options, for example, were ACPI, UEFI, IDE, LEGACY, RAID.  The Bios setup utility is built under the name APTIO.  Each incident prevented the laptop from booting and, instead, opened the bios setup utility.  With a less than thorough understanding of most of these values, a professional helped me reset the "migrant" fields to their appropriate values.

Question:  Since I did not previously even know how to access the BIOS setup utility and have not used the utility except for guided repairs, can anyone conjecture what may be causing these values to change "autonomously", or "on its own?"  I fear a similar incident causing an irrecoverable situation in the future.  Thanks in advance for any input.

BIOS info:

```
Version:      E1757IMS.509
Build:        4/24/13
EC Version:   1757EMS1, Ver5.05,
ME FW Ver:    9 . 0 . 2 . 1345
EC Build :    7/09/13
```

OS:

```
Windows 8.1 (now 10) on 2 X 128GB SSD Raid0,
Intel Haswell i7-4800MQ,
Cores = 4,
EMT64 = Supported,
Processor Stepping = 306c3,
Microcode Revision = 8,
IGFX VBIOS Version = 2170,
Memory 1,2 = 8GB,8GB (DDR3)
```

Answer (score 1):

> can anyone conjecture what may be causing these values to change "autonomously", or "on its own?"

My guess would be that the BIOS (and/or BIOS battery) had an error/failure or some kind, the BIOS lost all saved settings, and so reverted to the BIOS defaults.

Going from that assumption I'd suggest that, if possible on that model, start with replacing the BIOS battery with a new one.

Comment: Dell shipped a bunch of new laptops years back with defective bios batteries that wreaked havok with engineers until they figured it out, (with my help on the Dell forums), caused all kinds of bios settings changes and boot failures, also some weirdness while in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this sounds like a motherboard problem. AFAIK, BIOS settings are saved on a tiny flash chip on the motherboard (not necessarily on the same chip as the BIOS itself), so theoretically that chip is getting corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the BIOS/UEFI automatically change the boot order but never fields/settings that would cause a boot failure such as ACPI, UEFI, IDE, LEGACY, or RAID.

Is the electricity in your home stable and/or did you have nearby lightning strikes around the time of these events? Was the laptop's battery drained to a very low level prior to these incidents? Has the connector where the AC adapter plugs in been stressed by pulling/tripping on the cord? Have any liquids been spilled on the laptop? Note: I doubt the BIOS/CMOS battery is in need of replacement with such a new laptop but that's a possibility too.

Obviously I'm leaning towards something electrical but maybe it's the BIOS/UEFI itself. I see it's currently at version 509 (4.24.13) and that version 520 (11/28/14) is available at MSI's website. Depending on your answers to the electrical questions, you might want to update the BIOS but be careful. If you don't follow MSI's directions precisely, you could 'brick' (render useless) the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a most significant incident, I think this mystery is solved.  A few days after the post, one of the SSD's experienced a complete failure.  It is now in the interim of the warranty exchange, and I have completed a clean Windows install one the one remaining SSD.  My thinking and motive was to solve the BIOS field issue central to my question, but also (guided by the logic that all your suggestions were still valid) to assure myself that I wasn't dealing with a coincidence masking another problem.  The machine is working fine, therefore it seems the failing drive was causing BIOS to intermittently consider RAID an invalid option and was replaced by a default.  I thank you for your contributions and welcome comment and critique on my conclusion.